# Is it possible to return a JSON Object using fetch?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, jsx

I've been trying to use the fetch API to get a JSON Object since three days, I've searched on mostly all the threads I could find.
So I have a function which is using fetch, I want this function to return a JSON Object, but when I try to print it, it's a Promise Object. I've found that fetch IS actually returning Promise objects. So if it's impossible for fetch to return a JSON Object, how can I get a JSON Object from a Promise Object ?
The console.info in _ParseJSON print correctly the JSONObject that I want, but out of the fetch, it's impossible to reconstitute the JSON.

```
import React from 'react';

export class JSONObject {
constructor(_url) {
    this.URL = _url;
    this.importedJSON = null;

    this.state = {}; //Init getter setter
}

ParseCurrentUrl() {
    this.importedJSON = this._ParseJSON();
    console.info(this.importedJSON);
}

_ParseJSON() {
    return fetch(this.URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJSON) => {
            const { statusCode, data } = responseJSON;
            console.info("_PARSE");
            console.info(responseJSON);
            return responseJSON;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        })
}

set URL(_newUrl) { this.constructor.URL = _newUrl; }
get URL() { return this.constructor.URL; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have said that

***The console.info in _ParseJSON print correctly the JSONObject that I want, but out of the fetch, it's impossible to reconstitute the JSON***

that because you can not return a value inside a promise.

the lesson is **Asynchronous functions don't return (or at least, not reliably return)**

*If you want something to happen after an asynchronous function, you need to call it within of the asynchronous function*

you can use

```
_ParseJSON() {
    return fetch(this.URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJSON) => {
            const { status, data } = responseJSON;
            console.info("_PARSE");
            console.info(responseJSON);
            // set the value you want as an example
            this.importedJSON = responseJSON;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        })
}
```

instead

hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you, I've changed my function, but nothing changes.. I still get a Promise Object.. I'm really wondering if returning a JSON is possible...